# Replace substrings in string according to table in textfile

Tags: string, bash, replace

OS: Linux Mint, Bash: GNU bash, Version 4.3.11

I have a string like this:

```
(abc):seq1,seq2,whatever:(123seq3)
```

I want to replace `seq1` ... `seq3` according to a table like this:

```
seq1 name1
seq2 name2
seq3 name3
```

The table is in a text file and the delimiters in the table are actually tabs and not spaces like in the example. The to be replaced substrings (`seq1`, etc.) are to be identified only by their names. There is no delimiter in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your replacement table is stored in a file `table`, you can use

```
#!/bin/bash

string="$1"

while read from to; do
    string="${string//$from/$to}"
done < "$2"

echo "$string"
```

If this is stored in a file `script`, you can use it as follows:

```
./script '(abc):seq1,seq2,whatever:(123seq3)' table
```

and it will return

```
(abc):name1,name2,whatever:(123name3)
```

The script goes through the `table` file and, for each entry, replaces the corresponding strings using parameter expansion.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using awk here. Assuming that your string is stored in the variable `$string` and the replacements are in the file `table`, you could do something like this.

```
awk -v input="$string" '{ gsub($1, $2, input) } END { print input }' table
```

This replaces any occurrences of the string in the first field of each line with the contents of the second field. It assumes that the strings in the file don't contain any characters that would be interpreted as regex meta-characters, e.g. `*`, `&`, etc.